# How to order barplot by variable within fill in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm fixing a graph I found on the internet about men's and women's smoking rates in various countries, and I want to order it by men's smoking rates.

What I have here orders by men's smoking rates + women's smoking rates

```
countries <- c("China","Russia","Turkey","Greece","Israel","Germany","France",
              "Italy","Canada","United Kingdom","United States","India","Australia",
              "Brazil","Sweden")
women_rate <- c( 1.6,11.3,14.4, 17.9,12.6,18.6,15.4,12.7,12.3,12.5,12.7,1.7,10.4,7.3,6.8)

men_rate <- c(44.4,43.9,40.6,29.9,27.3,25.4,20.5,20.5,17.3,15.9,15.3,15.2,12.8,12.7,5.9)

country <- rep(countries, 2)
rate <- c(men_rate,women_rate)
gender <- c(rep("men",length(men_rate)),rep("women",length(women_rate)))

smoking_data <- data.frame(country,rate,gender)


library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)




ggplot(smoking_data, aes(x=rate,
                         y=reorder(country,rate),fill=gender)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity')
```

And it gives this resulting graph.

[image]

I want it to be ordered by men's smoking rates so China, Russia, Turkey, Greece, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `reorder` will order by the mean of all obs. per group, i.e. in your case the mean of men and women per country.

One fix would be to use a "helper column" where the values for women are replaced by `NA` so that only men values are taken into account when reordering. This could for example achieved by using `reorder(country, ifelse(gender == "men", rate, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(smoking_data, aes(
  x = rate,
  y = reorder(country, ifelse(gender == "men", rate, NA), na.rm = TRUE), fill = gender
)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]